# Using Webpack output.js file in Require.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, webpack

I have 2 projects. One with webpack.js, another with require.js. In my webpack project I have index.js with define construction example:

```
define([" "], function(){
...
return {"foo":"bar"} 
});
```

Then webpack returns output.js with the next

```
/***/ function(module, exports, webpack_require) {

 var WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY, WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;!(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY = [], WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT = function(){
  return {"foo":"bar"}

 }.apply(exports, WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY), WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT !== undefined && (module.exports = WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT))

/***/ }
```

In my require.js project I'm trying to load this amd module with define construction as well:

```
define(["output.js"], function(bundle){
   console.log(bundle) //undefined
});
```

File output.js was successfully loaded in browser network, any ideas? Please help.

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

Answer (score -1):

try to use :

```
define(["./output.js"], function(bundle){
   console.log(bundle) //undefined
});
```

probably it is not finding the file.  using the "./", 
probably solve your problem, I hope to have helped.